# Update JW Player Poster Image During Playback

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

Is there a way to update the `image:` during playback? We are using it for live audio and I would like to update the player with the album art.

Comment: how are you changing the audio? just using a stream and changing what you're streaming? or are you swapping audio files?

Comment: It's a continuous audio file, so there is no change of audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a live audio stream, then you will need to identify some event on your page in order to fire the function to update the image. Once you identify the event you want to tie it to, you can update the image using the following code.

```
jwplayer('player').load({
          "image": "newimage.jpg"
      });
```

Your player needs some way of knowing when the song has changed, how do you plan on identifying that?

Comment: If I use this in Chrome's console, it should work, right? It pauses the player whenever I use it there. As for the timing, we show title/artist info on the same page, so I have that trigger already made